# just install jboss-fuse but management console is not reachable

Tags: apache-karaf, jbossfuse

I have install jboss-fuse on linux centos and runt it. But management console is not reachable.

I have found some relevant documentation on redhat's website and followed the steps.

> https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Using_the_Management_Console/files/FMCUGAccess.html

In that document it is said fabric-webui is to be installed. So I have run this command; 
"profile-edit --features fabric-webui fabric"

But, An error occured during the installation. I found this exception in 'karaf.log' file.

> 2015-06-17 20:02:02,255 | ERROR | agent-3-thread-1 | DeploymentAgent
>   | .fabric8.agent.DeploymentAgent$2  255 | 60 - io.fabric8.fabric-agent
>   - 1.0.0.redhat-379 | Unable to update agent org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve
>   dummy/0.0.0: missing requirement [dummy/0.0.0] osgi.identity;
>   osgi.identity=fabric-webui; type=karaf.feature; version=0     at
>   org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates.populateResource(Candidates.java:285)[60:io.fabric8.fabric-agent:1.0.0.redhat-379]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates.populate(Candidates.java:153)[60:io.fabric8.fabric-agent:1.0.0.redhat-379]
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:148)[60:io.fabric8.fabric-agent:1.0.0.redhat-379]
>     at
>   io.fabric8.agent.DeploymentBuilder.resolve(DeploymentBuilder.java:226)[60:io.fabric8.fabric-agent:1.0.0.redhat-379]
>     at
>   io.fabric8.agent.DeploymentAgent.doUpdate(DeploymentAgent.java:521)[60:io.fabric8.fabric-agent:1.0.0.redhat-379]
>     at
>   io.fabric8.agent.DeploymentAgent$2.run(DeploymentAgent.java:252)[60:io.fabric8.fabric-agent:1.0.0.redhat-379]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)[:1.7.0_72]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_72]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_72]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_72]
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_72]

I have checked the continer list and result is shown below.

> [id]                           [version] [connected] [profiles]
>   [provision status] root*                          1.0       true
>   fabric, fabric-ensemble-0000-1, jboss-fuse-full    error -
>   org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve
>   dummy/0.0.0: missing requir

Can this problem be caused because maven has not configured yet ? Fuse use maven to collect dependencies but I haven't configured maven yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved.

It seems the logs and management console access problems are irrelevant.

The problem was firewall and we are able to access management console after stopping the firewall.

```
 systemctl stop firewalld
```

Also, It seems maven is not required for accessing to management console after installation.